# Multiple cursors (carets) at once functionality, just as in the Visual Studio Code but in every Windows application?

Tags: winapi, dll-injection, ntdll

Was wondering if this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics could be implemented with WinApi or by DLL calls/injection globally in every application?

Which api call could be relevant to get me started?

Comment: You would need to subclass all edit controls used by all applications, and the multiselect functionality you would essentially need to write from scratch, including custom painting, copy-pasting and whatnot, since there is no "please do multiline select for me" flag. For standard Win32/ComCtl controls this is doable, for WPF you might need an entirely different approach, and for applications that completely customize their editors you couldn't do it at all. This is an ambitious project; before embarking on it you should try to kill it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I wasn't aware of the one caret per queue limit, is a hard limit, and I didn't think of doing it by edit controls. Now I'm aware of that. Thanks. What I thought is here: https://pastebin.com/C4mXSypf . Yet to create proof of concept using AHK/AutoIt (and potentially discover any issues I didn't think of) and then rewrite it in C for speed. It's just a pseudocode. What do you think?

Comment: Even if you try to do as much on your own as possible, you would need a way to get data to/from the editor in question. Doing this piecemeal is hard to get right; doing it by complete replacement is inefficient. Like I said, this is an ambitious project. Nothing's stopping you from just trying it, but I suspect you will quickly run into a lot of "niggly bits" with regard to different applications not responding as nicely to your mouse or keyboard input as you'd like, or preventing you from overlaying windows.

Comment: Ultimately I sincerely doubt this is worth it as opposed to just using an editor that has built-in multiline editing support (like VS Code) and finding a way to get your input into the applications that don't have multiline editing support. What's so nice about the editing in other apps, anyway? :P

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done. There are too many problems that need to be solved for which there is no general solution.

The standard [carets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/carets) have a hard limit of [one caret per queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showcaret). With that in mind you would now have to solve not one, but **two** problems: Getting a custom caret implementation, and fighting the system-provided one.

That might still sound doable, but even just getting your custom-rendered carets injected into foreign windows isn't possible. There is no infrastructure in the system that allows you to safely tap into the rendering of arbitrary (or even standard) controls you do not own.

Now even if you got a solution to all of the above, how would you communicate those multiple selection marks back to client code? [EM_GETSEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-getsel) is strictly limited to one selection mark at most.

So far, this was mostly just about standard controls. Things won't get any easier with custom control implementations. WPF, to my knowledge, uses a pretty much closed down control library, that doesn't even provide the customization points of Windows' common controls. Same goes for UI toolkits like Qt. While open source, Qt doesn't allow for any external customization.

I'm sure there are more problems that don't have a general solution. While not an exhaustive list, the above problems prevent implementation of multi-selection in arbitrary UIs outside your control.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the one caret per queue limit, is a hard limit. Now I'm aware of that and treating it as a constant. Thanks.

What I thought is here: https://pastebin.com/C4mXSypf . Yet to create proof of concept using AHK/AutoIt (and potentially discover any issues I didn't think of) and then rewrite it in C for speed. It's just a pseudocode. What do you think?

Comment: You cannot render onto a window you do not own. Any attempt to draw your virtual carets and selection marks is going to be undone by the code that owns the window, at any time it sees fit. You don't know when that happens, and you won't get notified either. Not something you can control. There is no robust solution to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: it can be over the window. For example I have an transparent (clickable through) window drawn with current time over all windows displaying time https://i.imgur.com/98oIRSC.png I can still click on the close windows and other controls, and the window itself is unselectable... In full screen mode Firefox, if I send right click through that time window, it will still go straight to the browser. I have it as "+Owner +AlwaysOnTop -Resize -SysMenu -MinimizeBox -MaximizeBox Disabled -SysMenu -Caption -Border -ToolWindow" from https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Options

Comment: I can use the same thing, as explained in my previous comment to display virtual carets.

Comment: Sure, you *could* place  layered window on top of the client. But now you've put yourself into a position, where you need to solve another problem that has no general solution: **Where** are you going to draw your carets and selection markers? There is no infrastructure in the system that allows you to reliably query for something like line height, or even just learn, which font you'd have to use to render the selected text. Feel free to play around. I doubt there's going to be a robust solution to be found.